# Trouble with JDBC Persistence of ActiveMQ Artemis to MySQL

Tags: activemq-artemis

This is my first time trying ActiveMQ Artemis. I configured JDBC persistence to MySQL in broker.xml following the official documentation, and the broker starts up without any issues. However, I can't find the persisted message data in the table associated with the “message-table-name” tag. Can someone provide me with some hints or suggestions?
[image]
[image]

I have tried commenting out the folder persistence tags like “xxx-directory”, thinking they might be conflicting, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I've also switched database versions, but the issue still persists.

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis as an MQTT broker and have simulated both MQTT message publication and subscription using tools, without encountering any issues. I've considered the possibility of a mechanism that might be destroying subscriptions after a certain period of time. I've also attempted to inspect the MySQL storage situation when sending MQTT messages without subscribing. However, there's consistently no data present in the table associated with “message-table-name”. Interestingly, the table corresponding to “bindings-table-name” does contain data, indicating that the JDBC configuration is likely not the source of the problem.

Comment: What QoS are you using when you send your MQTT messages? Also, do you have any subscriptions active when you send the messages?

Comment: I apologize for not responding promptly. I am currently trying the solution you provided, and I will provide feedback on any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send messages where there are no subscriptions then the messages are not persisted. They are just dropped. This is normal pub/sub semantics.

Also, any message sent with QoS 0 will also not be persisted.

Therefore, you need to create a subscription first and then send a message with either QoS 1 or 2 to the topic where the client is subscribed. Assuming the client doesn't immediately consume and acknowledge the message you should then see it in the database.

For what it's worth, I recommend you use the file-based journal if at all possible. A relational database is really *not* a good solution for storing message data like this. The feature was added to help folks who were potentially migrating from another broker which used an RDBMS (e.g. ActiveMQ "Classic") or folks who simply "must" use one due to some internal policy. This is noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/persistence.html#jdbc-persistence).

Comment: I have subscribed to MQTT using @JmsListener in Java and added a sleep, as you suggested. Just as mentioned in the documentation and your response, I can now see the unprocessed QoS1 data in the corresponding message table. Due to internal policy reasons, I am unable to utilize a log-based approach, as you suggested. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!